# Chrome developer tools not reloading css

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I'm struggeling with the Chrome DevTools. I would like to optimize my workflow so I tried to configure Chrome to reload the css after compiling with `grunt-contrib-compass`. But I've tried now for two hours and Chrome won't reload my css file. Did I miss something?

**SERVER** ist running with XAMPP

**CHROME CONFIG**
[image]

GRUNT CONFIG

```
module.exports = function( grunt ) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        // JavaScript
        eslint: {
            all: [
                "Gruntfile.js",
                "js/app.js"
            ]
        },

        // CSS
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    importPath: "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss",
                    sassDir: "sass",
                    cssDir: "../assets/css",
                    noLineComments: true,
                    sourcemap: true
                }
            },
            deploy: {
                options: {
                    importPath: "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss",
                    sassDir: "sass",
                    cssDir: "../assets/css",
                    noLineComments: true,
                    environment: "production"
                }
            }
        },

        // Watch for changes
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ["sass/**/*.scss"],
                tasks: ["compass:dev"]
           },
           js: {
                files: ["js/**/*.js"],
                tasks: ["eslint"]
            }
        }

    });

    // Load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-compass");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("eslint-grunt");

    // Register Task(s).
    grunt.registerTask( "dev", ["watch"] );
    grunt.registerTask( "deploy", ["uglify"] );
};
```

**RESPONSE OF `grunt dev`:**

```
>> File "sass\_header.scss" changed.
Running "compass:build" (compass) task
    write D:/xampp/htdocs/defaultwp/wp-content/themes/wadt/assets/css/app.css (0.853s)
    write D:/xampp/htdocs/defaultwp/wp-content/themes/wadt/assets/css/app.css.map

Done. Completed in 3.455s
```

Comment: Make sure to turn on the "disable cache while devtools is open" option (in "Network" section of preferences). Or clear your cache. Or try running it from an anonymous window.

Comment: Thank you for that, tried it but same issue persists. I'm thinking about if the compiling time of ~3.5 seconds could be a problem for Chrome. Likewise I don't get the notice to reload the Inspector.